# Function to evaluate a salary between two dates, applying pro rata to partial months

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

I need a function that given an input of a start date, end date and a salary, will calculate the actual amount paid over the period.

I can do this using a calendar table with a sum and group by, but I'm wondering if a function would be better given I have many rows to calculate.

Where we have a partial month, it will pro rata using (salary / 12) / number of days in month * number of days paid.

So given 05 APR 2019, 15 APR 2019 and 250000 as inputs the calculation would be 
(25000 / 12) / 30 * 11 days (end dates are included) = 763.89

Given 05 APR 2019, 20 SEP 2019, 30000 as inputs the calculation would be 
(30000 / 12) / 30 * 26 days = 2166.67 (for April)

- 30000 / 12 * 4 (4 full months, May, June, July, August, full monthly rate) = 10000
- (30000 / 12) / 30 * 20 days = 1666.67 (for September)

So a total of 13833.34 for the period 05 APR 2019 - 20 SEP 2019

I can handle the first scenario, where the start and end date are within the same month, like this

```
declare @startdte as date = '05 APR 2019'
declare @enddte as date = '15 APR 2019'
declare @eomed int = day(DATEADD(MONTH,1+DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@enddte),-1)) --month end for end date
declare @salary as decimal(16,2) = 25000
select
case when year(@startdte) = year(@enddte) and month(@startdte) = month(@enddte) then @salary / 12 / @eomed * (datediff(d,@startdte, @enddte) + 1)
end
```

Then the only part I've been able to get down from the second example is this bit that will get the complete months

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month,@startdte-1,@enddte+1),0)-1,0)
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: SQL Sever 2008 R2 came out of extended support on 9th July 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not as simple as:

```
DECLARE @startdte AS DATE = '20180405';
DECLARE @enddte AS DATE = '20190415';
DECLARE @salary AS DECIMAL(16,2) = 25000;
SELECT
    @startdte AS [start_date],
    @enddte AS end_date,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startdte, @enddte) AS years,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdte, @enddte) - DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startdte, @enddte) * 365 + 1 AS [days],
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startdte, @enddte) * @salary
    + (DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdte, @enddte) - DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startdte, @enddte) * 365 + 1) / 365.0 * @salary AS salary_paid_over_period;
```

So count the number of years between the two dates, and multiply by the salary, then take the number of days between the two dates, take off the number of days representing complete years, then multiply this by the salary and divide by the number of days in a year.

Results:

```
start_date  end_date    years   days    salary_paid_over_period
2018-04-05  2019-04-15  1       11      25753.40
```

Comment: Using the second example with 20190405, 20190920 and 25000 it gives 11575.325, this would be the same as  select @salary * (datediff(d,@startdte,@enddte) + 1) / 365

Comment: Sorry, was using 25k instead of 30k. It gives 13890.39, correct calculation would be 13833.34, there was a mistake on my original post

Comment: It's because you are aggregating to month, and I am aggregating to day.  You don't get paid more for working a 31 day month than you would for working a 28 day month, so I suppose your method is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked it out.

```
declare @startdte as date = '05 APR 2019'
declare @enddte as date = '20 sep 2019'
declare @eomed int = day(DATEADD(MONTH,1+DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@enddte),-1)) --month end for end date
declare @eomsd int = day(DATEADD(MONTH,1+DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@startdte),-1)) --month end for start date
declare @salary as decimal(16,2) = 30000
select
case when year(@startdte) = year(@enddte) and month(@startdte) = month(@enddte) then @salary / 12 / @eomed * (datediff(d,@startdte, @enddte) + 1)
else 
(@salary / 12 / @eomsd) * (@eomsd - day(@startdte) + 1) --partial month from start date to end of month
+
datediff(month,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, @startdte), 0),@enddte) * (@salary / 12) --full months from first day of month after start date to end date
+
@salary / 12 / @eomed * day(@enddte) --partial months 
end
```